# Google Places Photos & copyrights

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I created a coordinates website that shows different information about a location. I pull this information from API's.

One of the things I show on the website are location photos that I pull from Google Places API.

Now I've received an e-mail from a professional photographer who says I'm infringing on his copyrights by showing the photo on my page. I've told him I pull the photo from Google Places and that he should contact Google if he doesn't want his photo on sites.

His reply is that I as website owner are responsible for the content and that Google has nothing to do with it. I find this very hard to believe...

What do you guys think? Any advice? Can ask Google for help?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos) has this to say about attribution:

> Photos returned by the Photo service are sourced from a variety of locations, including business owners and Google+ users contributed photos. In most cases, these photos can be used without attribution, or will have the required attribution included as a part of the image. However, if the returned `photo` element includes a value in the `html_attributions` field, you will have to include the additional attribution in your application wherever you display the image.

Did the photo in question have anything in the `html_attributions` field? If not, then you're correct that the owner needs to talk to Google. If it does and you didn't display it, then you are in breach of copyright.

Comment: Yeah I read that too late unfortunately. It did have an html_attribute which I didn't show.

Comment: I think you need to send the photographer a very humble apology for your error and how you compounded it with your initial response. But don't be surprised if you get a letter from some lawyers in the near future.

Comment: That won't work. Here in The Netherlands it's becoming their primary source of income I think. He send me an invoice of 200 euro. Unfortunately I was worng by not showing the html_attribute info so this time I will just pay it.